# POSIX regex for Version string

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, posix, regex-group

I have a source on which I have no control and I want to filter out all string which have some characters in it.
For example Out of these:

```
9
8.1.0
5.0
9.0
5.1
8.0.0
7.0 (cdfsdsdsd)
5.0.2
8
7.0.1
7.1
6.0
7.0
Over 32323
7.0 rdx K9 bnsm
9.2.3
8.oo
pp
unknown
8.0_vgfe10051988
6.0.1
8.0.0-derv10051988
9.1
9.0.0
8.0.1
7.0_xccv10051988
7.1.3
10.0
7.0.X.1.C
8.0.0_vged10051988
4.4.4
7.1.2
7.0 [NKL 24 | ABC]
8.1
7.1.1
5.1.1
7.0_Jgrd10051988
9.XXX
9.0.1
8.0
5.0.1
8.1.1
10
```

Out of these I need only those Strings with only digits and .

```
9
8.1.0
5.0
9.0
5.1
8.0.0
5.0.2
8
7.0.1
7.1
6.0
7.0
9.2.3
6.0.1
9.1
9.0.0
8.0.1
7.1.3
10.0
4.4.4
7.1.2
8.1
7.1.1
5.1.1
9.0.1
8.0
5.0.1
8.1.1
10
```

I have tried many regex, but nothing seems to be generic enough,
This regex is giving `[0-9]*.?[0-9]` Strings too.
The one I have got working is `^(\*|\d+(\.\d+){0,2}(\.\*)?)$`, but this is not POSIX.

How do I get a POSIX which also works on Redshift?

Comment: Try `^(\*|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,2}(\.\*)?)$`. It is POSIX ERE compliant.

Comment: When you say POSIX you should also clarify whether it is BRE or ERE syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sorry, but this doesnt seem to match any String

Comment: If the relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html), even `\d` should work, just write it as `\\d`. `'^(\\*|\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,2}(\\.\\*)?)$'`

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:Sorry, I forgot to update. Yes it worked! Thank you so much...

Comment: I posted an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60678346/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look of the Amazon document, it seems POSIX ERE is supported by the Redshift. Then would you please try:

```
^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works, you just need to use double backslashes in the string literal.

According to the [Amazon Redshift "POSIX Operators" documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html),

> Amazon Redshift supports the following Perl-influenced operators in regular expressions. Escape the operator using two backslashes (‘`\\`’).

So, you may use

```
'^(\\*|\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,2}(\\.\\*)?)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is:

```
^[.0-9]+$
```

If you don't have support for extended regex, you can do:

```
^[.0-9][.0-9]*$
```

I ran this command on your input and output and got an empty diff:

```
$ diff <(grep -P '^[.0-9]+$' input) output
$ echo $?
0
```

On your specific input, even `^[.0-9]*$` would work.

Note, however, that there's a difference between "Strings with only digits and `.`" and "version string". The simple regex will also catch inputs like:

```
1..2
..
.
0...
.1
```

If that's not a problem, you can use the simple regex.